# Change order of characters in each string in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array which contains strings like this :

```
Input = { 'BDCE'; 'BAFD'; 'HGAB' }
```

How can I change order of characters in each string in a cell array? The order is from 'A' to 'Z' 
The expected output should be like this :

```
Output = {'BCDE'; 'ABDF'; 'ABGH'}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's easy: use [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply the [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function to the string contained in each cell:

```
Output = cellfun(@sort, Input, 'Uniformoutput', 0);
```